# gcp cloud sql instance times out after 15 mins - "waiting for state to become 'DONE' (last state: 'RUNNING')

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-sql, terraform-provider-gcp

Should I increase the timeout? The database is up and running and everything works, it's just that terraform times out and then does not adopt/take the created database within the state.

On following runs it errors out saying instance with that name already exists -- although terraform created that to begin with.

I'm creating it via this module: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/GoogleCloudPlatform/sql-db/google/latest/submodules/postgresql using the postgresql submodule.

The creation works and I can connect to it and run operations, but obviously no further actions run on it, such as creating additional database users, database, etc.

Configuration:

```
module "postgresql-db" {
  source               = "GoogleCloudPlatform/sql-db/google//modules/postgresql"
  version              = "8.0.0"
  name                 = var.environment
  random_instance_name = true
  database_version     = "POSTGRES_14"
  project_id           = var.gcp_project
  zone                 = var.gcp_zone
  region               = var.gcp_region
  tier                 = "db-f1-micro"
  db_name              = "yeo"

  deletion_protection = false

  ip_configuration = {
    ipv4_enabled = true
    require_ssl  = false
    authorized_networks = [{
      name  = "public"
      value = "0.0.0.0/0"
    }]
  }
}
```

I don't think it has anything to do with the module itself, I looked at the source code and it merely attempts to create a `google_sql_database_instance` as such:

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "default" {
  provider            = google-beta
  project             = var.project_id
  name                = local.master_instance_name
  database_version    = var.database_version
  region              = var.region
  encryption_key_name = var.encryption_key_name
  deletion_protection = var.deletion_protection

  settings {
    tier              = var.tier
    activation_policy = var.activation_policy
    availability_type = var.availability_type

    dynamic "backup_configuration" {
      for_each = [var.backup_configuration]
      content {
        binary_log_enabled             = false
        enabled                        = lookup(backup_configuration.value, "enabled", null)
        start_time                     = lookup(backup_configuration.value, "start_time", null)
        location                       = lookup(backup_configuration.value, "location", null)
        point_in_time_recovery_enabled = lookup(backup_configuration.value, "point_in_time_recovery_enabled", false)
        transaction_log_retention_days = lookup(backup_configuration.value, "transaction_log_retention_days", null)

        dynamic "backup_retention_settings" {
          for_each = local.retained_backups != null || local.retention_unit != null ? [var.backup_configuration] : []
          content {
            retained_backups = local.retained_backups
            retention_unit   = local.retention_unit
          }
        }
      }
    }
    dynamic "ip_configuration" {
      for_each = [local.ip_configurations[local.ip_configuration_enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"]]
      content {
        ipv4_enabled    = lookup(ip_configuration.value, "ipv4_enabled", null)
        private_network = lookup(ip_configuration.value, "private_network", null)
        require_ssl     = lookup(ip_configuration.value, "require_ssl", null)

        dynamic "authorized_networks" {
          for_each = lookup(ip_configuration.value, "authorized_networks", [])
          content {
            expiration_time = lookup(authorized_networks.value, "expiration_time", null)
            name            = lookup(authorized_networks.value, "name", null)
            value           = lookup(authorized_networks.value, "value", null)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    dynamic "insights_config" {
      for_each = var.insights_config != null ? [var.insights_config] : []

      content {
        query_insights_enabled  = true
        query_string_length     = lookup(insights_config.value, "query_string_length", 1024)
        record_application_tags = lookup(insights_config.value, "record_application_tags", false)
        record_client_address   = lookup(insights_config.value, "record_client_address", false)
      }
    }

    disk_autoresize = var.disk_autoresize
    disk_size       = var.disk_size
    disk_type       = var.disk_type
    pricing_plan    = var.pricing_plan
    dynamic "database_flags" {
      for_each = var.database_flags
      content {
        name  = lookup(database_flags.value, "name", null)
        value = lookup(database_flags.value, "value", null)
      }
    }

    user_labels = var.user_labels

    location_preference {
      zone = var.zone
    }

    maintenance_window {
      day          = var.maintenance_window_day
      hour         = var.maintenance_window_hour
      update_track = var.maintenance_window_update_track
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      settings[0].disk_size
    ]
  }

  timeouts {
    create = var.create_timeout
    update = var.update_timeout
    delete = var.delete_timeout
  }

  depends_on = [null_resource.module_depends_on]
}
```

Any ideas on how to bypass this?

Comment: Does `terraform apply` pass if you run it again? (some "changes outside terraform been made" should show up)

If yes, then yes it's timeout problem. But if terraform still want to make changes (plan is not 'empty') then there is some other problem.

Could you also paste plan you get on second run? (be sure to not paste secrets)

Comment: @ravenwing it was totally the timeout, I've increased it to 30 minutes and it completed after about ~18 minutes with everything working

Comment: @SebastianG, if your question is already resolved, please post it as an answer so that it would be helpful to other community members with similar questions such as yours.

Answer (score 0):

As @SebastianG mentioned in his comment, the issue was fixed by changing the timeout to `30` minutes as resource completes after `~18` minutes.